# Python, argparse: correct handling of argument wildcards on both windows and linux

Tags: python, cross-platform, wildcard

It's known that Linux and Windows shells process wildcards like '*' and '?' differently. I'm aiming at writing simple cross-platform application and I want it to work with wildcards. The only "beautiful" way I see I can implement this is via subclassing the argparse.ArgumentParser and overloading parse_args method in order to expand all '*' and '?' manually by glob.glob. But I'm wondering why such option is not implemented at ArgumentParser yet. Maybe there are some drawbacks I don't notice and maybe there are some other common methods?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Windows, but in Bash, the `*` and `?` get expanded by the shell before your program ever sees them. The only way they wouldn't get expanded is if the directory does not have any matching file names. This ensures the user that wildcards always work the same way regardless of the program they're running.

In other words, wildcards are a shell feature. Your program has no control over them whatsoever.

EDIT: Actually, after looking at the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching), it *is* possible to see wildcards if the user does a little extra work. To prevent wildcard expansion, you could tell the user to either use a backslash to escape the wildcard (`\*`) or to put the word in quotes (`'myfile.*'`). Then you can process the wildcards however you want, possibly using the `glob` library.

Comment: The problem is that Windows does not expand wildcards so I have to do it in python.